# Cannot install any package using yum

Tags: yum, centos6.4

Whenever I try to install any package using yum i get the error as

"Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds"

Can anyone tell me why is this happening to me? I have already tried for 5 days to download 5MB using yum but I'm still struggling. Someone please tell me what is the reason? To be precise I am using Cent OS 6.4 and my location is Nepal.

When all the mirrors are tried it downloaded some files and for the remaining it said

"Error Downloading Packages:
  mysql-server-5.5.33-1.el6.remi.i686: failure: mysql-server-5.5.33-1.el6.remi.i686.rpm from remi: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try."

Comment: More information would be helpful. Was this ever working correctly? Is the machine healthy and can you download other things without any issues? What sort of download speeds do you get? Do you have any firewalls at play? Could you have a virus or leach on your system? Do you have any non-standard setup we should know about?

Answer (score 0):

It's blind shot but try `yum clean metadata && yum update`

Comment: i cant even use yum update :(

Comment: Did you try yum clean metadata before ???